# Get Entity instead of its ID in JSON response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get the list of all the `Users` entity that is present in my database. It has another entity, `Group` as its child element whose usage I would require after getting the users.

**User.java:-**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Integer userId;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "photo_url")
  private String photoURL;

  @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
  private String email;

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = Group.class, mappedBy = "admin", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
      CascadeType.MERGE,
      CascadeType.REFRESH
  })
  private List<Group> owningGroup;

  // Other functions
}
```

**Group.java:-**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
public class Group {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "photo_url")
  private String photoURL;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = {
      CascadeType.MERGE,
      CascadeType.REFRESH
  })
  @JoinColumn(name = "admin_id", nullable = false)
  private User admin;

  // Other functions
}
```

**The service class from where I'm getting the 'User' entity:-**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

  @Autowired
  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return this.userRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

When I am making a request to get all the users, this is what I'm getting:

```
{
  "@id": 1,
  "userId": 1,
  "name": "Devian Sonato",
  "photoURL": null,
  "email": "deviansonato@gmail.com",
  "owningGroup": [
    2
  ]
}
```

As you can see in `owningGroup` I am getting a int value, the `id` of the entity instead of the entity itself.

At first, I thought this is because I have set `FetchType` as `Lazy` but even after setting it as `Eager` I am still getting the ID instead of the entity.

What mistake am I making here? Would I need to fetch the group separately or should I not keep the list of Group-id inside the `User` object?

Comment: Are  you sure that join  column name admin_id

Comment: But in the user table I can see only Id column.

Comment: Add JsonManageReference and JsonBackReference on relationships.

Comment: @Anushan Does that needs to be in the user table? I have created column `admin_id` as a foreign key in Group table.

Comment: @S.Anushan I have used `@JsonIdentityInfo` for that, those two were not working.

Answer (score 0):

All code is right, can you try with the below code, hope it will help you.

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Group.class, mappedBy = "admin", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.All)
private List<Group> owningGroup;
```

Comment: I think I've tried using `CascadeType.All` but I think the problem here is with Jackson rather than hibernate.